# How to create a blank tic tac toe board, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Complete the function `create_board()`, which returns a nested list that (conceptually) represents a 2-dimensional Noughts and Crosses board, with each row having the length = 3. When first created, the board should be empty. Define an empty board cell as a single space character.

This is the starting function

```python
def create_board():
    """Create and return an empty board for Noughts and Crosses"""
```

and this should be the result

```
[[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

I just have no idea how to actually do that.

Comment: I'd really suggest reading the assigned text for your homework assignment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is geared more toward questions where you've made an attempt, have code to show, and want help with a specific problem with it. For a broad starting point, try your textbook and/or search online for tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a homework question where you need to learn some python.

```
def create_board():
    return [['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

or

```
def create_board():
    return [['']*3]*3
```

Comment: Shouldn't your second function still `return` the `[['']*3]*3` rather than just casting it into oblivion?

Answer (score 0):

According with your description all you need to do is returning  `[[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]`.

```py
def create_board():
    """Create and return an empty board for Noughts and Crosses"""
    return [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

You might also want a function visualize the board. You might use the code below for that.

```py
def print_board(board):
    """Prints the board"""
    print("\n---------\n".join([" | ".join(i) for i in board]))
```

Save this to a file and run the code. Then try making changes and see what happens.

```
board = create_board()
print_board(board)

print("\nAfter some moves")
board[1][1] = "X"
board[0][0] = "O"
print_board(board)
```